# Is it possible to create a trigger that executes when a record is inserted in one database but will ultimately insert into a different db?

Tags: mysql, sql, visual-studio, triggers

Using MySQL.  I have two databases that I am working with in my webapp.  One is called AUTH the other is Lab3.  What I want to do is when a record is inserted into "Auth" for that same record to be inserted into "Lab3".

Both of these DB's are in MySql.

My other solution is to just create two insert statements from my webapp that will just insert into both dbs.

Let me know of your thoughts.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sure.  Just provide the database prefix in the `INSERT`:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trig_test2 AFTER INSERT ON test2
FOR EACH ROW
INSERT INTO test2.test2 (copy) VALUES (NEW.copy+1000)
;
```

**The setup:**

```
USE test;

CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS test2;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test2.test2;
CREATE TABLE test2.test2 ( id int primary key auto_increment, copy int );

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test2;  -- current database "test"
CREATE TABLE test2 ( id int primary key auto_increment, copy int );

DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS trig_test2;

INSERT INTO test2 (copy) VALUES (100);

CREATE TRIGGER trig_test2 AFTER INSERT ON test2
FOR EACH ROW
INSERT INTO test2.test2 (copy) VALUES (NEW.copy+1000)
;

INSERT INTO test2 (copy) VALUES (101);
INSERT INTO test2 (copy) VALUES (102);
INSERT INTO test2 (copy) VALUES (103);

SELECT * FROM test2;

SELECT * FROM test2.test2;
```

**The result:**

```
--------------
SELECT * FROM test2
--------------

+----+------+
| id | copy |
+----+------+
|  1 |  100 |   <-- Inserted before the trigger was created.
|  2 |  101 |
|  3 |  102 |
|  4 |  103 |
+----+------+
4 rows in set

--------------
SELECT * FROM test2.test2
--------------

+----+------+
| id | copy |
+----+------+
|  1 | 1101 |
|  2 | 1102 |
|  3 | 1103 |
+----+------+
3 rows in set
```

Comment: In multiple-database environ it is safe to specify the database alias to each object. I.e. `CREATE TRIGGER trig_test2 AFTER INSERT ON database1.test2`.